# Cognito Developer Authenticated Identities with Node

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to create a login system with Node as the backend/web service for the app, also with an iOS app.  I'm trying to use Amazon Cognito to do this, but I can't figure out how to register/authenticate users from either end.  The only tutorials I've been able to find use Facebook login, which don't help me.

Edit: I have  unauthenticated identities working somewhat, but I'm still clueless as to the authenticated developer identities.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems have you run into trying to implement your solution?

Comment: @jsve I'm still having a hard time grasping the concept, but I think that I have enough to go off of.  I honestly haven't gotten as far as trying to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I understand you are looking specifically for a Node sample, we do have a full [end-to-end sample](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3E3NJURV1LNV1/Integrating-Amazon-Cognito-using-developer-authenticated-identities-An-end-to-en) with a Java backend and iOS and Android clients.

The clients also handle transition from unauthenticated to authenticated, linking multiple logins with your developer identity and more. Hopefully this will help fill the gaps you have. If not, please let us know what we can do to improve.

Comment: Could Java act as a backend with Node running as a client (like iOS and Android are)?

Comment: @Tillson What is your use case for using node as a client?

Comment: We use Node to run the application's web interface.  It acts as content management for what can be seen inside the iOS app.

Comment: @Tillson in general the answer to your question is "yes", but you will have to manage the proxy between your Node application and the backend.

Comment: Would having the backend on Node instead of Java be a better choice in the long run, in your opinion? We are moving the entire app from Parse to AWS currently, and the entire website is already written in Node.

Comment: @Tillson in general, the less moving parts the better. Having to maintain both your Node backend and the Java backend seems like complexity that you should be able to avoid.